# Python(Django) :I want the payment form(code) triggered whenever a user clicks the submit button and only saved into DB if payment is succesful

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, payment-gateway, form-submit

I am currently using DJANGO
How can I make the payment form(code) triggered when a user clickn submit and also make it saved into DB after successful payment. Please help me out.. i have been  trying to solved this days back.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Promoting(models.Model):
    yourname= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    fathername= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    mothername= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    imagefield=models.ImageField(upload_to='postedimages')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.promoterauthor
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Promoting
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        yourname=request.POST.get('yourname')
        fathername=request.POST.get('fathername')
         mothername=request.POST.get(' mothername')
        imagefield=request.FILES['imagefield']       
 newdata=Promoting(promoterauthor=promoterauthor,websiteurl=websiteurl,tagline=tagline,imagefield=imagefield)
        newone.save()
        return render(request, 'success.html', {})
    else:
        return render(request, 'homepage.html', {})
```

Here is my form

```html
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data class="contactForm">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="yourname" id="yourname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Youur username"  required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="" class="form-control" name="fathername" id="fathername"  placeholder="Your Website"  required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mothername" id="mothername" placeholder="Add a Tag line"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagefield" id="imagefield" placeholder="Your image"  accept="image/*" required>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

**The form submits successfully into the database and also my payment gateway(Rave by flutterwave.COM is working well)n I ONLY NEED A WAY TO LINK BOTH TOGETHER**

Precisely, what I want is the payment form triggered once the submit button is clicked and I only want a the data saved into DB if only payment is successful .. please help out
The code snippet from my payment gateway also works when the pay button is clicked... 
Here it the payment code

```html
<form>
    <script src="https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/flwpbf-inline.js"></script>
    <button type="button" onClick="payWithRave()">Pay Now</button>
</form>

<script>
    const API_publicKey = "FLWPUBK-152e7e9e17c0f7e985f9fee5838eafcc-X";

    function payWithRave() {
        var x = getpaidSetup({
            PBFPubKey: API_publicKey,
            customer_email: "user@example.com",
            amount:5,
            customer_phone: "234099940409",
            currency: "USD",
            txref: "rave-123456",
            meta: [{
                metaname: "flightID",
                metavalue: "AP1234"
            }],
            onclose: function() {},
            callback: function(response) {
                var txref = response.tx.txRef; // collect txRef returned and pass to a      server page to complete status check.
                console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
                if (
                    response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "00" ||
                    response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "0"
                ) {
                    // redirect to a success page
                } else {
                    // redirect to a failure page.
                }

                x.close(); // use this to close the modal immediately after payment.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[THIS IS WHAT IS GENERATED BY THE PAYMENT CODE WHEN PAY IS CLICKED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgCxh.png)

Comment: You need to use Django forms or model forms and get data from cleaned_data

Comment: @Rarblack Thanks for answering... I am now able to submit the data into database
But i need a way to integrate the payment in such a way that whenever a user wants to submit those information the payment option provided up here will be triggered also the data in the form is submitted only after successful payment. Thankk

Comment: @ray did you ever get the way around this?